# VS2017 nuget package files treated as link instead of actual file

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to create a nuget using the csproj file. My files are copied, but my log4net.config (and others) are treated as a link when the nuget package is imported by another project. These files are also not copied to the target directory on build. (see the blue icon in the screenshot below)

[image: log4net as a "project" link]

My cs project contains the following code.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="contentFiles/**/*.*;log4net.config" copyToOutput="true">
    <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    <CopyToOutput>true</CopyToOutput>
    <BuildAction>Content</BuildAction>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

What do I need to do so that the log4net.config:

1 - is not treated as a linked file

2 - is copied to outbut directory by default.

Answer (score 3):

> What do I need to do so that the log4net.config: 1 - is not treated as a linked file

This is by design. `contentFiles` are supposed to be added as a link. Copying files into the project's source directory is not supported and has been a discouraged practice for classic projects.

Check Martin`s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921546/nuspec-contentfiles-not-added-to-a-project):

> This is by design. **NuGet packages are no longer supposed to modify the project's source but only add to its built output or build process (in addition to .NET libraries).** The content folder for adding sources to the project is only continued to be supported for packages.config based projects since it would be a breaking change for existing projects, but projects using project.json or PackageReference (VS 2017) get the new behaviour.

Now, The `contentFiles` section controls the msbuild items that are generated for these files into the `obj\projectname.csproj.nuget.g.props` file.

> 2 - is copied to outbut directory by default.

You can set `copyToOutput="true"` for the `log4net.config` in the .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xxxx</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/Views/log4net.config" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
  </metadata>

    <files>
      <file src="contentFiles/any/any/log4net.config" target="contentFiles/any/any/log4net.config" />
    </files>
```

You can check the document [NuGet ContentFiles Demystified](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751019/packing-static-content-in-nuget-for-packagereferece-projects) for more details.

Comment: How can fix the the "bad relative link" added to Project Files then? VS2019. `<Content Update="C:\Users\bad_link_that_should_not_be_in_source\some_content">`

Comment: Ahh.. it's added to the project [only] when the build action, etc. is modified.