# Copy files to Android project on NuGet installation

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, nuget

## Desired output

We want to distribute a `.dll` (NetStandard project) and some files through the NuGet package installation. When installing it in a `Xamarin.Android` project:

- A file ([`Directory.Buil.props`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build)) is copied to the solution folder
- An executable (`config.exe`) is copied to the project folder
- A directory (`Files`) and its contents are copied in the project folder

## Problems

- Projects using [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) will not get the files copied (`content` not supported)
- For some reason, when using a `.nuspec` file; source files, `obj`, `bin` etc. are packed too

## Solution

Ideally, we would like to:

- only use a `.csproj` file (without `.nuspec`)
- not have both `content` and `contentFiles` packed in the `.nupkg`
- easily access the `.dll` from the `.csproj`
- when installing a newer `.nupkg` version, old files will be overwritten

## Questions

**(1)** Is this doable with `PackageReference` and `contentFiles` ?

**(2)** What's the best approach you can think of ?

Thanks.

## Responses

**Leo**:

When installing the package in an Android project, the files don't appear in the project. Not to mention that the files are just referenced and not copied (even if I had `copyToOutput="true"`):

[image: Solution projects after NuGet package installation]

**Leo** (edit):

I cannot use the new SDK csproj format. Taken from your link:

> **Disclaimer**: this only works for a small set of project types.
>
> - class library projects
> - console apps
> - ASP.NET Core web apps
> - .NET Core
>
> If you are building ASP.NET 4 (i.e not ASP.NET Core), WPF, Universal Windows, or Xamarin projects, you’ll have to stick with the old format

Answer (score 0):

> (1) Is this doable with PackageReference and contentFiles ?

I am afraid you could not add those files to the Android project, but I would like provide an alternative solution here, add those files to the output folder.

You could use `PackageReference` and `contentFiles` directly for the latter two requirements, `config.exe` and `Files`. But for the first requirement `Directory.Buil.props`, we need do more things, since it is copied to the **solution** folder rather than **project** folder.

**For the latter two requirements**, `config.exe` and `Files`, we could use `.nuspec` file with `contentFiles` to including them, need set `copyToOutput="true"`, like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2011/08/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyTestCore</id>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
    <authors>TestContentFile</authors>
    <owners>TestContentFile</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/config.exe" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Files/1.txt" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
      <files include="any/any/Files/2.txt" buildAction="content" flatten="true" copyToOutput="true"/>
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>

  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/config.exe" target="contentFiles/any/any/config.exe" />
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Files/1.txt" target="contentFiles/any/any/Files" />
    <file src="contentFiles/any/any/Files/2.txt" target="contentFiles/any/any/Files" />
  </files>
</package>
```

After packing this `.nuspec` and install the generated package to the project.

**However**, we could not find those files under the References node. That because the project still use the old csproj with `packagereference` not using the new sdk csproj.

[Old csproj to new csproj: Visual Studio 2017 upgrade guide](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/03/09/vs2015-to-vs2017-upgrade/)

Besides, copying files into the project's source directory is not supported and has been a discouraged practice for classic projects. The `contentFiles` section controls the msbuild items that are generated for these files into the obj\projectname.csproj.nuget.g.props file. And check the `project.assets.json` file you can find:

```
  "targets": {
    "MonoAndroid,Version=v7.1": {
      "MyTestCore/5.0.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "contentFiles": {
          "contentFiles/any/any/Files/1.txt": {
            "buildAction": "Content",
            "codeLanguage": "any",
            "copyToOutput": true,
            "outputPath": "1.txt"
          },
          "contentFiles/any/any/Files/2.txt": {
            "buildAction": "Content",
            "codeLanguage": "any",
            "copyToOutput": true,
            "outputPath": "2.txt"
          },
          "contentFiles/any/any/config.exe": {
            "buildAction": "Content",
            "codeLanguage": "any",
            "copyToOutput": true,
            "outputPath": "config.exe"
          }
        }
```

See: [nuspec contentFiles not added to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45921546/nuspec-contentfiles-not-added-to-a-project)

Then we need build this project, those files will copied to the output folder.

**For the first requirement**, in order to add the `Directory.Buil.props` to the solution folder, we need create a custom copy target in the `YourPackageName.targets` file, then add this .targets file into the `\build` folder, the .targets file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <ItemGroup>  
        <MySourceFiles Include="<FilePath>\Directory.Buil.props"/>  
    </ItemGroup>  

    <Target Name="CopyFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">  
        <Copy  
            SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"  
            DestinationFolder="<SolutionFolder>"  
        />  
    </Target>  

</Project>
```

The .nuspec file like:

```
  <files>
    <file src="<>\xxx.targets" target="build" />
  </files>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This isn't working on an Android project. I added an edit with the results.

Comment: @JonZarate, That is my fault. I forgot test it with Android project, just test it with `PackageReference`. I have updated my answer with more info, you can check the **However...** pieces for details. Hope this can give some helps :) .

Comment: I added another response. Have you tested this before posting ?

Comment: @JonZarate, Yes, I have test it. Have you seen the word "we could not find those files under the References node." and "those files will copied to the output folder."? Do you want add those files to the project under the References node? If yes, I afraid I could not give other useful help :(.

Comment: I guess I am missing some steps then. Could you upload the solution and link it ?

Comment: The solution: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHf2S8UfYEi1QfQ2pb5 And the test nuget package: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ai1sp_yvodHf2TCEl2mY1dt0dyDN

Comment: I just tested it, it's not working. When I install your `MyTestCore.nupkg` package in the `TestAppSample.Android` project, the files are not copied in the project folder.

Comment: Have you built your project? Those file will be copied to the output folder **NOT** project folder after you build your project.

Comment: I know, but I didn't ask to copy the files to the *output* folder, I asked to `Copy files to Android project on NuGet installation`. You answered `The answer is yes.` and provided a solution, now I am telling you that it's not fulfilling the initial requirement. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Please, edit your answer. It's fine if you want to provide an alternative solution, but don't claim to answer my question. It is misleading for other readers.

Comment: @JonZarate, Yes, you are right. I have not noticed that. I accept your advice. I have update my answer, you can check it. Thanks for the suggestion :).